# Turning querys in to subquerys pls?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, subquery

I need some help turning this set of querys in to a single query, could someone help me please?

```
$occurrences = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM occurrences WHERE close_id_user order by close_date desc limit 10");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($occurrences)){
    $computers = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM computers id='".$row['id_computer']."'");
    $row_computers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($computers);
    $manufacturers = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM manufacturers WHERE id='".$row_computers['id_manufacturer']."'");
    $row_manufacturers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($manufacturers);
    $clients = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='".$row_computers['id_client']."'");
    $row_clients = mysqli_fetch_assoc($clients);
}
```

Comment: You need to look into SQL joins.

Comment: What ceejayoz said. However, even with JOINs you may not be able effectively to do it all in a single query if you have multiple 1-to-many relations on the same table (as it appears is a possibility with `computers` and it's relations to `manufacturers` & `clients`). _Btw, just googling "simple join example" should be enough to point you in the right direction._

Comment: Can you show us the query you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say for sure what the best query is to combine the 4 in your question. The difficulty is that you don't include how to combine them. We can see that the relationship between each table is based on computer_id, client_id, and manufacturer_id, but it's difficult to discern the effects of your `while` loop and how it would translate to a `Join`.

Just the same, something like the following should get you close:

```
SELECT *
FROM occurences
    LEFT OUTER JOIN computers ON occurences.id_computer = computers.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN manufacturers ON occurences.id_manufacturers = manufacturers.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clients ON occurences.id_client = clients.id
WHERE close_id_user
```

Here we use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to bring in each table. This insures that you will get all records from `occurences` comes through regardless if any of the other three tables have a matching value to their respective `id` field.

Take a look at the results in your system and then tweak the query from there to get the result set into a format that will work for you.